# Dilemma working with skillful subordinates

Tags: php

This is not a technical question but more to managing technical expectation to myself. Currently i am just along managing website (WP based), managing web services, do some web development works in this company. Some projects i need to outsource, manage the outsourcing until the project is complete. I am not a powerful PHP developer (i just have the basics), but i love Wordpress, so most of the project i use WP as the platform.

Even i am alone, i am quite happy because my work more to managing than doing the hard coding. But the time has come i need to grow this team, i have found skillful developer and designer to join my team. They are very skillful, have great portfolios.

My boss want me to find a great team so my team can grow. My dilemma now is i am afraid if i approve the new candidates to my team than maybe i will be removed from the team sooner or later since i am not skillful as them, even i am more senior than them in this company.

On the other hand, i heard it is great to work with more skillful person as you can develop yourself faster.

Now i am stuck which way to choose.

Comment: This would probably fit better at programmers.stackexchange.com.

Comment: then learn php , practice and read books. or find a better job you are good at.  I know there is always somebody better than us. but it also comes down to trust and how serious you are in working.  P.S. I don't think stackoverflow is the right place to post this question

Comment: Holding a project back because you're afraid somebody may realize you're not as good as somebody else is unprofessional and mostly unfounded fear. Anyway, voted to move to programmers.SE.

Comment: Sounds about right. I've never had a project manager who was as technically adept as any of the developers on the team

Comment: @Tim Post, any reason this is closed instead of moved to Programmers.SE?

Comment: The question is not constructive and can likely only be answered by the person asking, after he has chosen and seen how that plays out. In other words, nobody can predict the future. As such, it will likely be closed on programmers.se as well.

Comment: This has come up a few times (in various incarnations) on Programmer's SE, and hasn't gone over too well there.

Answer (score 3):

A good `Project Manager` has a different skill set than a good `Developer`. If you're better at keeping things organized, delegating tasks, and making sure tasks get done, then you'll be a fine PM. Developers like to have PM's who are developers, so that we don't have to explain the issues of programming.

It also makes good business sense to move someone in your position to a post where you wont be slowing down the progress of the project by mediocre programming skills; Instead, you'd be *improving* projects by keeping the communication channels open, and making sure each part gets taken care of.

Additionally, you might want to focus on your debugging skills so that you can help sort out code issues when a developer gets stuck. Simply acting as a sounding board is often enough to help most developers work through their problems.